# Заставить Joomla! 3.x выделить нужный пункт меню

Tags: joomla, joomla3

Известно что `Joomla!` выделяет пункт меню минимум по двум критериями, по `URI` и параметру `Itemid`.

В ЧПУ сайта выставлен нужный `Itemid=103` (в моем случае) но нужный пункт меню все равно не выделяется.

В компоненте видно, что параметр `Itemid=103` приходит в скрипт.

Как заставить Joomla! выделить нужный пункт меню, если ЧПУ адрес не совпадает с алиасом пункта меню?

Answer (score 0):

Элемент стандартного меню (item menu) получает особый класс (css)  current active или просто active, если открыта страница с Itemid=103 то элемент меню ( li ) у которого имеется класс item-103 получает дополнительный класс  "current active" благодаря которому уже в стилях прописывается определённые свойства для активного меню. Если элемент меню не выделяется, возможно в стилях не обозначены свойства для класса .active

Comment: Выделить меню я могу любым способом в том числе и программно написать условия, имелось ввиду заставить Joomla! управлять модулями так как будто это меню выбрано. А не просто поменять CSS стили.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь , если честно, очень трудно понять вашу проблему исходя из прочитанного вопроса.. "заставить Joomla! управлять модулями так как будто это меню выбрано" . Вы хотите активировать (показать) какой-то модуль независимо на каком меню (Itemid) оно активированно? я правильно понял заданный вопрос?

Comment: нет не правильно, модулями я тоже умею управлять. надо из вне джумлы или из компонента или из плагина заставить ее выделить нужный пункт меню так что бы все модули на этой странице тоже сработали если они привязаны к этому пункту меню, что тут сложного...

Comment: есть сложный компонент, который написан мной, у него 5 уровней вложенности в структуре каталога, двигаясь по этим адресам джумла выделяет тот пункт меню, к которому привязан данный компонент, но проблема в том что на главной странице тоже этот компонент и джумла всегда показывает что пользователь якобы на главной странице хотя он на самом деле находится по адресу типа `/moscow/moscow/buy/cats/abissinskaya/`

Comment: адресов огромное количество вариантов и невозможно указать через админку для меню все адреса из этого каталога, соответственно надо виртуально как то заставить джумлу думать что она на адресе /a/ хотя она на адресе /b/

Comment: "что тут сложного" - сложностей не было бы если сразу в первом вопросе описали полную суть проблемы как описали в последних двух коментах(!) 
Конечно не будет работать... для Joomla, сео ссылка которую вы собрали через router.php неизвестна и поэтому для фреймворка /index.php или /moscow/moscow/buy/cats/abissinskaya/ - это одно и тоже. Если нет меню - стандартным методом не вызвать активацию модулей , вам надо в view.html.php вашего компонента програмно написать условие и вручную вызывать работу модулей, например через $renderer->render(JModuleHelper::getModule(‘нужный модуль’), $params);)